# Find the respective conditions for a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & \alpha& 0  \\
    \beta       & 1 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

where α and β are non-zero complex numbers, find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
Find the respective conditions for (a) the eigenvalues to be real and (b) the
eigenvectors to be orthogonal. Show that the conditions are jointly satisfied if
and only if A is Hermitian.

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: I got alpha*beta>0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\alpha$ and $\beta $ are conjugate the product is real and the eigenvalues are real $(1,1-\sqrt{\alpha\beta},1+\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$

Eigenvectors are $$\vec v_1=(0,0,1),\vec v_2=\left(-\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}},1,0\right),\vec v_3=\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}},1,0\right)$$

If $\alpha=\beta$ the vectors are orthogonal, indeed they become
$$\vec v_1=(0,0,1),\vec v_2=\left(-1,1,0\right),\vec v_3=\left(1,1,0\right)$$
$\vec v_2\perp \vec v_3$ because $\vec v_2\cdot \vec v_3=0$

and $\vec v_2\times \vec v_3=(0,0,-2)$ which is parallel to $\vec v_1$

so the three vectors are mutually orthogonal

Hope this helps

Comment: I just they are conjugate to keep dot production real. Thanks a lot.